# After the revocation of an Olympic medal, do those who took lower places get upgraded?

Tags: olympics, awards, doping

Recently, there are numerous news about the Russian Olympic players being stripped of medals. There have been [many similar cases in the past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stripped_Olympic_medals), too.

Once a sportsperson gets stripped of their medal, **do the others get "upgraded" automatically?** In other words, if the gold medal was stripped, does the player who took second place automatically get "promoted" to the gold, the third to the silver, and so on?

If so, what is the process? What happens to a sportsperson who took fourth place, did not even appear on the podium, and lost their deserved moment of glory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per this [BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/sport/athletics/40746615), the athletes will receive medals that were stripped from the banned competitors:

> Britain's 4x400m relay squad from the 2008 Beijing Games got their
>   podium moment in front of a home crowd at the London Anniversary Games
>   last month, finally becoming Olympic medallists after a nine-year
>   delay.
>
> They are among dozens of athletes who are receiving medals after their
>   competitors were disqualified retrospectively and stripped of their
>   achievements because of doping offences.
>
> The new approach of the International Olympic Committee (IOC), as part
>   of a stated commitment to supporting clean athletes, is to "honour
>   accomplishments in a more systematic manner".

In the article, the writer interviewed a number of athletes that were suddenly Olympic medalists, often years after the fact. Some athletes received another medal ceremony in front of fans, another actually received a gold medal at a food court!

These competitors were naturally delighted to receive their medals, but also had mixed emotions - some had lost training support that would have been granted as a reward for medaling, and several missed a chance to receive an acknowledgement in front of an Olympic crowd at the competition.

Finally, the article notes:

> The IOC says the reallocation process is not automatic and is done on
>   a case-by-case basis.